# Typescript Recursive String Interpolation

Tags: typescript, string, types, string-interpolation

I'm working on a simple (but hopefully type-safe) system that represents timeSlots as strings.

```js
// example
const t1 = "|mon::10:30|";
const t2 = "|fri::20:00|";
```

So far I have managed to type these timeSlotStrings using string concatenation:

```js
export type Weekday = "mon" | "tue" | "wed" | "thu" | "fri" | "sat" | "sun";
export type TimeSlot = "08:00" | "08:30" | "09:00" | "09:30" | "10:00" /*...*/ "19:30" | "20:00";

export type TimeSlotString = `$|${Weekday}::${TimeSlot}|`; // <- there you go!

const t1: TimeSlotString = "|mon::08:00|"; // OK! ✅
const t2: TimeSlotString = "|sat::17:30|"; // OK! ✅
```

But now I need to type the resulting string of concatenating `TimeSlotString` many times. The type should be called `TimeSlotsConcat` but I'm not sure this is possible, if it is, then what the syntax would look like?...

```js
// example:
type TimeSlotsConcat = ❓❓❓ // <- what type would satisfy s1 and s2?

const s1: TimeSlotsConcat = "|mon::10:30||tue::14:30||wed::08:00|";
const s2: TimeSlotsConcat = "|tue::11:00||tue::14:30||thu::18:00||fri::12:30|";
```

I tried using the `TimeSlotString` type recursively, but no luck...

```js
type TimeSlotsConcat = "" | `${TimeSlotString}` | `${TimeSlotString}${TimeSlotsConcat}`;

//  ❌ ERROR: Type alias 'TimeSlotConcatStrings' circularly references itself.
```

So here goes the QUESTION: Is there a way to represent `TimeSlotsConcat` in typescript?

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation instead of arrays or some other collection type?

Comment: No, there is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to that set of values. TypeScript unions can only represent a finite collection of types, and anything more than 10,000 members or so is going to give you problems. Your `TimeSlotString` has 175 members, a pair has 30,625 members which is already pushing the limits, and triplets are too much. The best you can do is write a generic *validation* type, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB13bw) shoes. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?